# How to decrypt and encrypt iphone backup using python IOS 10.1.1?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, encryption

So I'm getting closer, but I can't seem to get this line of code to work just yet: key = manifest["kb"].unwrapKeyForClass(record.protection_class, record.encryption_key[4:])

Attached is the code I have so far, but I still can't wrap my head where to find this information within the backup. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
from hashlib import md5
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import os
import re
import sqlite3
from keystore.keybag import Keybag
from util import readPlist, makedirs
import sys
import plistlib

showinfo = ["Device Name", "Display Name", "Last Backup Date", "IMEI",
            "Serial Number", "Product Type", "Product Version", "iTunes Version"]

def extract_backup(backup_path, output_path, password=""):
    if not os.path.exists(backup_path + "/Manifest.plist"):
        print "Manifest.plist not found"
        return
    manifest = readPlist(backup_path + "/Manifest.plist")

    info = readPlist( backup_path + "/Info.plist")
    for i in showinfo:
        print i + " : " + unicode(info.get(i, "missing"))

    print "Extract backup to %s ? (y/n)" % output_path
    if raw_input() == "n":
        return

    print "Backup is %sencrypted" % (int(not manifest["IsEncrypted"]) * "not ")

    if manifest["IsEncrypted"] and password == "":
        print "Enter backup password : "
        password = raw_input()

    if (manifest["IsEncrypted"]):
        manifest["password"] = password
        manifest["kb"] = Keybag.createWithBackupManifest(manifest, password)
        makedirs(output_path)
        plistlib.writePlist(manifest, output_path + "/Manifest.plist")

        decrypt_backup10(backup_path, output_path, manifest)

def extract_all():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        mobilesync = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "/Apple Computer/MobileSync/Backup/"
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        mobilesync = os.environ["HOME"] + "/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/"
    else:
        print "Unsupported operating system"
        return
    print "-" * 60
    print "Searching for iTunes backups"
    print "-" * 60

    for udid in os.listdir(mobilesync):
        extract_backup(mobilesync + "/" + udid, udid + "_extract")

def decrypt_backup10(backup_path, output_path, manifest):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(backup_path + "/Manifest.db")
    try:
        connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        for record in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Files"):
            extract_file(backup_path, output_path, record, manifest, kb)
    except:
        connection.close()

def extract_file(backup_path, output_path, record, manifest):
    # read backup file
    try:
        fileID = record["fileID"]
        filename = os.path.join(backup_path, fileID[:2], fileID)
        f1 = file(filename, "rb")
        print(filename)
    except(IOError), e:
        #print(e)
        print "WARNING: File %s (%s) has not been found" % (filename, record["relativePath"])
        return

    # write output file
    output_path = os.path.join(output_path, fileID[:2], fileID)
    ensure_dir_exists(output_path)

    print("Writing %s" % output_path)
    f2 = file(output_path, 'wb')

    aes = None
    if manifest["IsEncrypted"] and manifest["kb"]:
        key = manifest["kb"].unwrapKeyForClass(record.protection_class, record.encryption_key[4:])
        if not key:
            warn("Cannot unwrap key")
            return
        aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, "\x00"*16)

    while True:
        data = f1.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        if aes:
            data2 = data = aes.decrypt(data)
        f2.write(data)

    f1.close()
    if aes:
        c = data2[-1]
        i = ord(c)
        if i < 17 and data2.endswith(c*i):
            f2.truncate(f2.tell() - i)
        else:
            warn("Bad padding, last byte = 0x%x !" % i)

    f1.close()
    f2.close()

def ensure_dir_exists(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))

def main():
    extract_backup(input, output, password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```